# How do i create my own Auditing in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In my Project I want to implement more than 4 default fields which gives by AuditingEntityListener. I want to implement UpdateHistory which has fields of [updatedBy,updatedAt,updatedFieldName]. When I extend this class to each entity function should happen. In that function when i update the values that property should be in updatedFieldName list.

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Getter
@Setter
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class BaseEntity {
    @CreatedBy
    @Column(updatable = false)
    protected String createdBy;

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(updatable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    protected Date createdAt;

    @EmbeddedId
    protected List<Updated> updateData = new ArrayList<>();

    // Method to update trial
    public void updateTrial(List<String> fieldNames) {
        Updated updated = new Updated();
        updated.setUpdatedBy(updated.getUpdatedBy());
        updated.setUpdatedAt(updated.getUpdatedAt());
        updated.setFieldNames(fieldNames);
        this.updateData.add(updated);
    }

}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Embeddable
public class Updated {
    @LastModifiedBy
    protected String updatedBy;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    protected Date updatedAt;

    protected List<String> fieldNames;
}
public UserResponse updateUser(Long id, UpdateUserRequest updateUserRequest) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        User existingUser = this.findUserById(id);
        List<String> changedFields = new ArrayList<>();

        this.compareEntities(existingUser, updateUserRequest, changedFields);

        modelMapper.map(updateUserRequest, existingUser);

        existingUser.setId(id);
        existingUser.setRoles(setToString(updateUserRequest.getRoles()));
        existingUser.updateTrial(changedFields);

        User updateUser = userRepository.save(existingUser);
        return mapToUserResponse(updateUser);
    }

    private void compareEntities(User existingUser, UpdateUserRequest updateUserRequest, List<String> changedFields) {
        // Compare property values and add different property names to the list
        if (!existingUser.getFirstName().equals(updateUserRequest.getFirstName())) {
            changedFields.add("firstName");
        }
        if (!existingUser.getLastName().equals(updateUserRequest.getLastName())) {
            changedFields.add("lastName");
        }
        if (!existingUser.getPhone().equals(updateUserRequest.getPhone())) {
            changedFields.add("phone");
        }
        if (!existingUser.getBusiness().equals(updateUserRequest.getBusiness())) {
            changedFields.add("business");
        }
        if (!existingUser.getDepartmentId().equals(updateUserRequest.getDepartmentId())) {
            changedFields.add("departmentId");
        }
        if (!existingUser.getPlantId().equals(updateUserRequest.getPlantId())) {
            changedFields.add("plantId");
        }
        if (!existingUser.getStatus().equals(updateUserRequest.getStatus())) {
            changedFields.add("status");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Don't go down that rabbit hole. Instead use something like HIbernate Envers or JaVers to do this for you, don't do it yourself.